# Trigger fired in periods

Tags: t-sql, triggers

Can I make a trigger that is fired every x hours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is what Scheduled Jobs are for.
See if [this](http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/sql-server-jobs.html) helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server you can use SQL Server Agent for doing repetitive jobs.

Answer (score 0):

No, Triggers are dependent upon rows being inserted, updated or deleted. The only way that you could have a trigger fire every few hours is to create a separate table and insert a row every few hours. shahkalpesh is correct, this was not the intended functionality for a trigger